# How to load image from file into picturebox using C# windows form using Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some problem regarding to my project. I'm using C# windows form using Microsoft Visual Studio.

Can anyone help me how to load image from file into picturebox? I have 300++ on image folder.

The system can search by work no., empl no. or name on text box. Then after user typing and click enter on the textbox, the employee details with image appears on the picture box.

All the image is name according to their work no.

The information details is retrieve from database but image from folder. Can anyone help me please :)

Comment: What do you have so far? What have you tried so far?

Comment: currently the system just appears the empoyee details such as department, passport and etc if searching by name, employee no. and work no. But cannot display image in picturebox.

Comment: You'll need to post your current code pieces so we can help you.

Comment: This is my current code to load the image into picture box.                    
                                                                                                                **if (file.Contains(textBoxWorkNo.Text))
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine("C:\\photo", textBoxWorkNo.Text) + ".jpg");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File not exist");
            }**

Answer (score 6):

`pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"your image file path");`

you can use a `OpenFileDialog` to get the file path

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This is my code to load the image from folder. But does not work. 'if (file.Contains(textBoxWorkNo.Text)) { pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine("C:\\photo", textBoxWorkNo.Text) + ".jpg"); } else { MessageBox.Show("File not exist"); }'

Comment: it seems that your path is not correct. (there are two file extensions.)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\MyPict.jpg");
```

In response to your code posted in the comment, give this a try:

```
const string imageFolderPath = @"C:\photo\";

var imageName = textBoxWorkNo.Text;
var fullImagePath = imageFolderPath + imageName + ".jpg";

if (File.Exists(fullImagePath))
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(fullImagePath);
else MessageBox.Show("File not exist");
```

Comment: It just to display image in picturebox right? I want appears image according to their work no. Because I have 300++ image in the folder.

Comment: That's correct. If you're looking for someone to write the full program for you, this is probably not the right site. On the other hand, if you have a more specific question, I'm happy to work with you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This is my code to load the image from folder. But does not work.  **if (file.Contains(textBoxWorkNo.Text))
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine("C:\\photo", textBoxWorkNo.Text) + ".jpg");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File not exist");
            }**

Comment: I've updated my post in response to your comment. Hope this helps.