# How to change Button image in Windows Forms (C#)?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am pretty new to C# and working on a application built with Visual Studio and WinForms.

I have a Button and I need to change its image when it gets clicked.

```
bool isButtonPressed = false;
..
..
private void myButtonBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isButtonPressed) {
        myButton.Image = ??
    }
    else {
        myButton.Image = ??
    }
    isButtonPressed = !isButtonPressed;
}
```

If you can be precise on what to do with examples I'd be grateful, also saying what namespace to use if I have to add one.

Comment: well it depends on where the image is coming from

Comment: i can use an img i have on my pc, a local img

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647276/how-to-load-image-from-file-into-picturebox-using-c-sharp-windows-form-using-mic

Comment: thx but i need a relative path, does it works?
for relative i mean a path to a folder inside my project, so if i push the project via git, and another person download it, the image get loaded with no problems

Comment: you can include the image in your resources as well

Comment: **using System;** will be needed as a namespace.
 Also this is how you can do what you want to do:

  `myButton.Image = Properties.Resources.ButtonNotPressedImage; `

  `myButton.Image = Properties.Resources.ButtonPressedImage;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps to **get your images from project resources**:

1. Add an `Images` folder to your project.
2. Add two images to this folder.
3. Right-click your project and select Properties.
4. Switch to the Resources tab on the left.
5. From the toolbar select Images from the first dropdown.
6. Drag the images from the Solution Explorer and drop to the Images panel.
7. Build your project.

Now you can get your `Button` images via

```
myButton.Image = Properties.Resources.Image1;
```

Resources tab and the images may look like this:

[image]